# Get Coordinates of view on which longpressGesture recogniser is added

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have added longpressGesture recognizer on view & given `NoofTouchesRequired=2`.I want to get the coordinates of both the views on which i have longpressed.

MyCode is as below:-

```
 //---long press gesture---

   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector (handleLongpressGesture:)];

  longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 4;

  longpressGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

  [viewLongPress addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];

  [longpressGesture release];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIGestureRecognizer` has a `locationInView:` method just for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)handleLongpressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)reco{
    UIView *theSuperview = self.view;
    CGPoint touchPointInSuperview = [reco locationInView:theSuperview];
}
```